# PostgreSQL: call EXTRACT function passing as argument one field of the query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to know if it is possible to use the extract function :

```sql
EXTRACT(field from timestamp)
```

Where the *field* is a value from the query?

Please see this (simplified) example:

```sql
SELECT c.name, EXTRACT(f.frecuency from NOW())
FROM contacts c 
INNER JOIN frecuencies f ON c.id = f.contact_id
```

From the following tables:

```
contacts table: 
---------------------
| id   |   name     | 
---------------------
| 123  |   Test     | 
---------------------

 frecuencies table: 
---------------------------------
| id | contact_id | frecuency |
---------------------------------
| 1  |   123      |  DAY        |
---------------------------------
```

I made the query (in several ways) and got the message:

```
timestamp with time zone units "frecuency" not recognized
```

Therefore I want to know if exists some workaround for this.

Thank you in advance.

PD: If you think the question title or body need to be improved please go ahead, I would thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `date_part` which [according to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) is the same as `EXTRACT` like in this example:

```
WITH units(u) AS (VALUES ('day'))
SELECT date_part(u, current_timestamp) FROM units;
┌───────────┐
│ date_part │
├───────────┤
│        18 │
└───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz, that is what I needed!